# My goal is to have the icon be replaced by text when hovered. Issue im having is all the icons move to the left when an icon is hovered

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical side-bar containing icons using a column in flexbox. My goal is when an icon is hovered the icon is replaced by text, Example A house icon when hovered says Home. The problem i am having is when The text appears all the icons not being hovered move to the left. I would like for them to remain centered. Thank you for the help!
MY HTML.

```
    <ul class="main-links">
      <li><a href="Home.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i><b>Home</b></a></li>
      <li><a href="About-Me.html"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="Education.html"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="Tools.html"><i class="fas fa-tools"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact.html"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
```

My CSS.

```
.main-links li i{
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    background: #181818;
    width: 22.5px;
    height: 21px;
}

.main-links li :hover i{
    display: none;
}

.main-links li b{
    display: none;
}

.main-links li :hover b{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: use visibility instead of display to not disturbe the layout

Comment: What is "b" that you are using in your selectors? This code isn't really functional at all. Please adjust it.

Comment: The <b> tag is written as <b></b> with the text to be bold inserted between the start and end tags. Im not sure what is not functional in my code? please elaborate. I used the b tag because i dont know of another way to separate the icon and text.